# Having issues getting a Scene to redraw

Tags: python

I recently started learning Python and just finished my courses on it on CodeAcademy, so I've been trying to come up with small projects to do in order to practice and really learn this language. What I'm trying to do is create a clock that will change colors as the time changes, I have the scene drawn but the time doesn't change with it, how do I get the scene to redraw every second?

```
from time import strftime
from scene import *

current_time = strftime("%b %d           %Y %H:%M:%S")

hour = int(strftime("%H"))
min = int(strftime("%M"))
sec = int(strftime("%S"))

class Clock (Scene):

    def draw (self):
        self.hour = hour
        self.min = min
        self.sec = sec
        background(0, 0, 0)
        fill(0, 0, 0)
        w, h = self.size.w, self.size.h
        rect(w * 0.5 - 100, h * 0.5 -   100, 200, 200)
        s = 40 if self.size.w > 700 else 17
        text(current_time,
            'Futura', s,   *self.bounds.center().as_tuple())
        dead = set()

run(Clock())
print current_time
print hex(hour)
print hex(min)
print hex(sec)`
```

Comment: I tried running your code and got `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`. Please advise.

Comment: I think dead = set() may be the culprit, I was doing this on my phone since I'm at work, so the indents may be a little off.                                Edit: Current_time = strftime may also be the issue, idk how it got so many spaces

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :-) One more question. What is `scene`?

Comment: Honestly idk, I started off just using the import time, then I went and found some code on the app I'm using that makes the popup box and it was called scene, I'm using pythonestia when I'm not home in order to practice more easily

Comment: The OP is using the [`scene`](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/scene.html) package, apparently, which is included in Pythonista which is a Python distribution for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You are only calculating the hour, minute, and second once, at the beginning of the script. `second` doesn't know that it represents the second, it just knows that it's a dumb integer. That's why it doesn't update itself when the time changes.

Try moving the `strftime`s into the `draw` method, so they execute every time the screen is redrawn.

```
def draw (self):
    current_time = strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
    hour = int(strftime("%H"))
    min = int(strftime("%M"))
    sec = int(strftime("%S"))
    self.hour = hour
    self.min = min
    self.sec = sec
    #...etc
```